# Windows Phone 7 set resource string value to .xml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to set a string in .resx to a .xml that is located in my project?

For instance,

Name = FileName  Value = Project.Objects.File.xml Comments = my xml file

and then parse through the resource Name instead of "file.xml" entering something like Resource.Filename?

```
var streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(Resource.FileName, UriKind.Relative));
        XDocument xdoc;
        using (var s = streamInfo.Stream)
            xdoc = XDocument.Load(s);
```

Im looking to do something like this, but obviously this is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question but received a lack of response on here...

Turns out I did not need to to set a FilePath for the Value on the FileName string.  Simply setting the value to examplefile.xml, allowed for the ResourceStream to work properly.